# What is the difference between `A*B*C` and `A*B + A*C` interaction when running a linear regression?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, interaction

Let's say I have a response variable `Y`, and I want to predict it using variables `A`, `B` and `C` using a linear regression model. My problem is that I suspect that `A` and `B` might interact as well as `A` and `C`, but not `B` and `C`. Thus, I think that interaction `A*B*C` might not be the most appropriate. However, I don't know how to set this type of relationship among explanatory variables.

In my real example, my response variable is the activity (`Activity`) of an animal, and my explanatory variables are the hour of the day (`Hour`), the moon illumination (`moon`) and the human presence (`human`). Following what I said in the first paragraph, I know that the moon effect changes depending on the hour of the day since not all the hours have the same type of moon. On the other side, the human presence occurs only at some specific hours of the day, so I also know that the "human presence" effect will depend on the hour of the day. But here, I don't want to consider the interaction between "moon" and "human". So, my doubt is what would be the right way of designing my model considering that `Hour` interact with `Moon` and `Human` but separately.

What is the correct way of designing a regression model considering these conditions?. Should I consider it as `Hour*Moon*Human` or as `Hour*Moon + Hour*Human` or none of them?

Any comment would be of great help

Comment: Your first comment to the answer confirms this really is an `R` question, as I pointed out yesterday.

Comment: It is both, which is not a problem, isn't it?  My doubt was that I didn't know how to consider interactions given my knowledge about the variables. This is a theoretical doubt. Then, I also had the doubt about how to write my desired interactions.

Comment: In my first comment, as I pointed out, is an extra doubt. In the post what I show is not a problem of code, at least not completely.

Answer (score 2):

`Hour*Moon + Hour*Human` is fine, it includes the three varibles plus the two interaction terms you are interested to, for a total of five regressors. I'm assuming you are using R notation.

Mind that `Hour` is a [circular variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circular-statistics), so modeling a linear relation on it, in most cases, is a bad idea. Whatever terms you want to use from `Hour`, just interact them with `Moon` and `Human`. For instance: `(cos(Hour)+sin(Hour))*(Human+Moon)`.

Comment: Yes @carlo, I know that `hour` is circular, and notation is in R, however, I didn't specify exactly what because it is not the point. One doubt, `Hour*Moon + Hour*Human` and `Hour*(Moon + Human)` is the same in `R` is the same?

Comment: yes____________

Comment: @Dekike whenever I get confused with interaction terms, I find it helpful just to write them out individually as I want them to appear rather than to depend on R to parse them out in a way I might not have intended. If you want only Hour-Moon and Hour-Human interactions plus the individual contributions of those predictors, I'd write `Hour + Moon + Human + Hour:Moon + Hour:Human` (putting aside the issue of the circular-variable nature of `Hour`).

Comment: Thanks, @EdM. One thing, I thought that writing `hour*moon + hour*human' would also include the individual contribution of `hour`, `moon` and `human`. However, what I extract from your comment is that I have to include those variables individually to include their contribution, is that true?

Comment: @Dekike when `R` encounters `Hour*Moon + Hour*Human` it effectively expands both of the "`*`" terms into their components--`Hour + Moon + Hour:Moon + Hour + Human + Hour:Human`--and then removes the redundant term to get `Hour + Moon + Human + Hour:Moon + Hour:Human`. Unlike the "`*`" syntax, "`:`" does not expand out an interaction but leaves it as is. So your are OK if you use "`*`", no need to specify individual predictors. If you use "`:`" you need to include the predictors individually yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @EdM for the explanation. I didn't realise that `:` and `*` were different things. I thought both means the same!! Thanks again for your time.

Comment: @Dekike one can't edit comments after 5 minutes, only delete and re-post at the end of the comment trail. So if I did that, future readers of your question and this answer wouldn't understand what was going on. I wrote "Hour-Moon and Hour-Human interactions" in the first comment specifically not to assume either of "`*`" or "`:`" but just to represent the generic concept of an interaction.